# Watson Assistant - Spel | Updating array

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I was trying to use Watson Assistant JSON Editor 

Now this is the setup

```
Entities
@action = eat,run,play

Context Variable
$list = [0,0]

I want to update my list if an action is detected
List[0] will be the size
List[1] will be the position[0]
```

Trying that on Spel JSON

```
 "$list":"<? entities['action'] != null ? $list.set(0,entities['action'].size()) and $list.set(1,entities['action'].location[0]): $list.set(0,0) and $list.set(1,0) ?>"
```

If an "and" operator was added it returns "True" | $list=True 
 instead of my array updating to $list['size']['location']

I can only achieve this by adding another context variable that holds the boolean part

```
"sample": "entities['action'] != null ? $list.set(0,5) and $list.set(1,5) : $list.set(0,0) and $list.set(1,0)"
```

any idea how to get same output using 1 variable?

Comment: Could you add an example of the list before and after the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it set list to "True" is that this expression: `"$list":"<? entities['action'] != null ? $list.set(0,entities['action'].size()) and $list.set(1,entities['action'].location[0]): $list.set(0,0) and $list.set(1,0) ?>"` 
will assign in the end the resulting value of the boolean check to the list variable hence over-writting the modifications done by the expressions. This is the default WA behavior that is used to update context variables (e.g. when your write `"my_string" : "value of the string"`

If you want to modify the list array only, you should use the second approach you suggested with another variable `sample` - that  will be updated with the resulting value of the SpEL expression so the `list` will not be overidden.